# Scroll loading for a simple data list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to implement a simple gridview in ASP.NET-MVC with a vertical scroll when it scroll down some data add to the end I mean loading data by scrolling down.

I couldn't load all of data in loading time.

For example in my GMail account when I had a lots of emails they was loading when I scrolled down.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are third party components a possibility?

The previous company I worked at implemented their own scrolling grid and it was a huge drain on resources making it work in various browsers and maintaining it. If you're able to use a third party control, I'd certainly recommend it - that way it's more likely to be well tested and stable.

The Telerik control supports what you want:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/client/virtualscrollpaging/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: And it is so slow and heavy also.

Comment: There is no any ASP.NET MVC version

Comment: Apologies, I somehow overlooked the whole MVC thing :(

Comment: Actually the do have a Free set of MVC tools: http://www.telerik.com/community/free-products.aspx  The license on them is that you can't make for the product you build with them.  You can use them all you want until you make money, then they would like to make money.